# Is there any use of software fault injection apart from testing coverage of existing tests?

Tags: debugging, testing, automated-tests, code-injection

Let's say I have published this project containing a function:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I have written the tests:

```
assert(1==1);
assert(2==2);
```

All the tests pass and so I claim that my project is 100% good and tests have 100% coverage.

My client is smart and knows about fault injection. So he injects a fault in my project and makes it:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
  return -1;
}
```

My tests still pass and so he says my tests are useless. Great.

**But** is there any other use of software fault injection?

I read that it is used to assert robustness of a software? How? Can you use this example and show that is possible?

Also, I was reading some papers that showed how faults can be injected in SOAP messages passed around in the web **(**basically meaning that messages that were being sent from one machine to another in the web were injected with faults and the results were observed***)*. How is this going to be useful? Obviously this will go wrong and what can you conclude from it?

Please quote with simple examples.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to injecting faults into SOAP messages (or other data sent over the wire): that could be viewed as a form of "stress testing", to determine how robust your application is in the face of network problems, data corruption, malicious clients, and so on.

As you said, "obviously this will go wrong". But the purpose of stress testing isn't to see if your application works as intended (under normal conditions). When you feed the application garbage data/massive volumes of data, deliberately corrupt config files, or suddenly disconnect hardware which is being used, etc., it's expected that your program will not "work". But you want to make sure it will not do something bad like crashing, destroying valuable data, revealing confidential data to unauthorized persons, and so on. If it is an application which services multiple users at the same time, you also want to make sure that illegal input from one user cannot result in a loss of service to other users.

If you have never stress tested your application, the results will probably surprise you!